# No DEBUG constant define, #if DEBUG returns true on release build

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

We have a console app, that we use to call DbUp (create db, update, test data, etc..).

We have a configuration, Stable, that is configured to NOT define the DEBUG constant:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Stable|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Stable\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Yet when this gets run on Octopus, this always returns true and holds up the deployment:

```
#if DEBUG
Console.ReadLine();
#endif
```

When I switch to the Stable configuration locally (VS), it runs and exits as expected.

When I switch to the Debug configuration locally (VS), it runs and waits for input, as expected.

If I comment out the lines completely, it runs fine on Octopus (exits, deployment finishes on Octopus).

This has me questioning all my choices in life.

Any idea why this may be happening?

EDIT - Command used to build the project (using TeamCity)

```
# Database
Invoke-Msbuild "$rootDir\artifacts\output\Database" `
             "$rootDir\MyClient.Database\MyClient.Database.csproj" `
             -target 'build' `
             -toolsVersion 4.0 `
             -maxCpuCount 8 `
             -VisualStudioVersion 14.0 `
             -logPath "$rootDir\artifacts\logs\Database" `
             -namespace 'MyClient' `
             -customParameters @('/property:RunOctoPack=true', "/property:OctoPackPackageVersion=$version", "/property:OctoPackNuGetProperties=env=$environment")
```

Comment: How and where is this build? You aren't providing the constant on the msbuild commandline?

Comment: TeamCity is where it is built, where it is creating a nuget package and pushing it to Octopus

Comment: Updated my question with the command used to build the console project.

Comment: Shouldn't you have an `/property:Configuration=Stable;Platform="Any CPU"` somewhere in that Invoke-MsBuild call or is `Stable|AnyCPU` the default in that csproj file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Build servers build. Octopus deploys.

So i do not think that Octopus has something to do with this problem.
Do you have a build server like TeamCity? Perhabs is there something wrong in the configuration?

EDIT:

Do you try this Parameter?

> -MsBuildParameters "/target:Clean;Build /property:Configuration=Stable;Platform=""Mixed Platforms""

Comment: Yes, I realize that. It is built using TeamCity, a nuget package is created and pushed to Octopus, where it gets run on a tentacle. I've added the code that I use to build the project.

Comment: Sigh, this is what happens when you look at code past midnight. Thank you!